# Maven parent pom profile is shadowed by settings.xml

Tags: maven-3

I am using Maven repo and it is configured in settings.xml

```
<settings>
<mirrors>
<mirror>
<id>nexus</id>
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
<url>http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
</mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
<profile>
<id>nexus</id>
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>central</id>
<url>http://central</url>
<releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
<snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
<id>central</id>
<url>http://central</url>
<releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
<snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
<activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Having a maven project in this order

```
parent
|
+child1
|
+child2
|
+child3
```

And configured profiles in parent pom,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>parent</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
    <module>child3</module>
  </modules>

  <profiles>
  <profile>
  <id>p1</id>
  <modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
  </modules>
  </profile>
  <profile>
  <id>p2</id>
  <modules>
    <module>child2</module>
    <module>child3</module>
  </modules>
  </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Now I want to build only child1 & child2, so I give the following command

```
mvn -P p1 clean
```

It is building all childs (child1, child2, child3)

```
mvn -P p1 help:active-profiles
```

shows following profiles are active,

- nexus (source: external)
- p1 (source: com.test:parent:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

How I can build only selective projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you like to build a single child in your multi-module build you should use the command line like this:

```
mvn -pl child1 clean package
```

and may be you need to give

```
mvn -pl -amd child1 clean package
```

but don't use profiles for such purposes.